# Как создать красивую анимацию кнопок в стиле Material Design?

Tags: android, анимация, material-design

Здравствуйте!
Хочу сделать красивую анимацию кнопок по всем канонам Material Design. Если поточнее, то у меня есть окно секундомера. В верхней половине будет находиться текст с отсчетом времени помещенный в круглый прогресс бар. А под этим прогрессом хочу разместить одну круглую кнопку отцентрованную по горизонтали (внешне как FAB) при нажатии на которую, она будет раздваиваться на две, как бы с эффектом капельки, и уже будет две кнопки **Пауза** и **Круг**. А так же обратный эффект, когда при нажатии на кнопку, две кнопки сливаются в одну.
Не посоветуете ресурсов (кроме погуглить, это я и так делаю) где можно научиться делать подобные эффекты. Конечно желательно новую информацию, в которой используются возможности Material Design и современные методы реализации.